# Zero knowledge proof for value of a hash function

Tags: cr.crypto-security, hash-function, zero-knowledge

Is there a zero knowledge proof which demonstrates that Peggy knows a value v whose hash-function is w?

In my understanding of the general theorems on zero-k there EXISTS such a function if the has-function has polynomial time complexity. However, I would like to know how such the protocol would look like for the case of SHA-256. My problem is, that the usual proof requires me to reduce the fact of having a certain SHA-256 to Graph 3 Coloring, for example, and I do not see how this could be done practically.

Answer (score 7):

In the rump session of Crypto 98, [Hal Finney](http://finney.org/~hal/) provided a talk which might be of your interest. The title is "A zero-knowledge proof of possession of a pre-image of a SHA-1 hash." I have not found any transcripts.<s>, but the video is available on both [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jQsSIdGTwo) and [Google Videos](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-5745972992365920864). (the videos are no longer available; see the comments below.)</s> The video is now available from my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxSJdYnjz8zdVG9qR0xiX191V28/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: the links no longer work. any chance you could summarize?

Comment: @mulllhausen: As far as I understood, the idea is to use a special (malleable) commitment to the preimage, give the commitment to the verifier, and then replace the internal SHA-1 operations with special operations acting on the commitments. Finally, the verifier gives back the result to the prover, who decommits it, and shows it to equal to the SHA-1 image. Hal Finney does not give much detail into what the commitment and the special operation are, but concludes that the implementation took a few hours to execute. I'll upload the video on some temporary file hosting, and post the link next...

Comment: @mulllhausen: I uploaded the video [here](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gedec10fb4a58cced9994404442c2b677ac88b8b92), so that you can watch it for yourself. Please note that this is a temporary file hosting, and will be deleted after 14 days.

Answer (score 2):

There is an elegant and rather efficient zero-knowledge protocol for these kinds of NP statements given in this paper:

- Marek Jawurek, Florian Kerschbaum, Claudio Orlandi: [Zero-Knowledge Using Garbled Circuits: How To Prove Non-Algebraic Statements Efficiently](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/073) (CCS 2013)

In fact, SHA-256 preimage is the example they list in the abstract. Maybe this old question inspired their paper? ;)

The protocol is based on garbled circuits. There is also some more recent relevant followup work optimizing the garbled circuit constructions that can be used in this protocol:

- Tore Kasper Frederiksen, Jesper Buus Nielsen, Claudio Orlandi: [Privacy-Free Garbled Circuits with Applications To Efficient Zero-Knowledge](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/598) (manuscript)
- Samee Zahur, Mike Rosulek, David Evans: [Two Halves Make a Whole: Reducing Data Transfer in Garbled Circuits using Half Gates](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/756) (manuscript). Disclaimer: self promotion alert!

Using the privacy-free garbling scheme in our latest paper, a zero-knowledge proof for one round of SHA-256 involves sending 1.5MB of garbled circuit data (with 128-bit secure garbling) plus a small number of oblivious transfers. I don't think the numbers I have for SHA-256 reflect a circuit that has been optimized for garbling, though.